# Why I don't see the reorderablelist in the editor in the inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The goal is to create a simple reorderable list.
For now it's not showing anything in the inspector.

The mono is attached to empty gameobject :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ReorderablelistTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public List<Transform> myTransforms = new List<Transform>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

The editor is in the Editor folder :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ReorderablelistTest))]
public class ReorderablelistTestEditor : Editor
{
    private ReorderablelistTestEditor reorderablelistTestEditor;

    [SerializeField] private ReorderableList myTransformsList;

    private SerializedProperty myTransforms;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        reorderablelistTestEditor = (ReorderablelistTestEditor)target;
        myTransforms = serializedObject.FindProperty("myTransforms");

        myTransformsList = new ReorderableList(serializedObject, myTransforms)
        {
            displayAdd = true,
            displayRemove = true,
            draggable = true,

            //drawHeaderCallback = DrawMyTransformsHeader,
            //drawElementCallback = DrawMyTransformsElement,

            /*onAddCallback = (list) =>
            {

            }*/
        };
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        myTransformsList.DoLayoutList();

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

For start I want to see the simple reorderablelist of myTransforms List in the inspector.

Comment: Why is it tagged `HideInInspector` in the first place?

Comment: right, removed the hideininspector attribute

Answer (score 0):

so first of all you should see a big `InvalidCastException` for

```
reorderablelistTestEditor = (ReorderablelistTestEditor)target;
```

what you want here is not a `ReorderablelistTestEditor` but rather the targeted type `ReorderablelistTest`.

Right after fixing this it "works" for me, the list appears in the editor **BUT** of course still without any drawer for the elements still you haven't implemented that yet so with fixing it to

```
private ReorderablelistTest reorderablelistTest;

...

reorderablelistTest = (ReorderablelistTest)target;
```

currently it will look like

[image]

---

**In general**

- Be aware that in newer Unity versions actually the reorderable list is finally the default drawer for any list/array so you might not even need this at all.
- Careful with the `target`. Usually you don't really need access to it. Whenever possible rather go through the `SerializedProperty`s.